# Windows Phone 7 Security Issues

Tags: security, windows-phone-7, owasp

I was looking into **OWASP Top 10 Mobile Risks** for security issues to be kept in mind while developing mobile applications. They have given very good information pertaining to Android and iOS platforms. Some notable ones include Client Side Injections, iOS Abusing URL Schemes, Android-Abusing Intents, Keystroke logging, Screenshots/iOS Backgrounding, Logs etc.

These were very useful and now I want to know **if there are any new vulnerabilities that exist in Windows Phone 7** , which were not present in Apple iOS and Google Android.

My requirement is, I need to build somewhat like a **Damn Vulnerable WP7 App** to educate the WP7 developers in my project to build secure applications for our clients.

OWASP has already built iGoat (iOS application) and DroidGoat (Android application) for the sake of iOS and Android developers. I dont see any such application for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently WP7 appears to be a very secure OS. Whilst I am sure it has vulnerabilities, these have not been exploited yet. Interestingly AVG released an anti-virus / malware app for WP7. This was pulled from the marketplace because it didn't actually do anything since there are no viruses for the phone yet!

http://www.winrumors.com/microsoft-pulls-avg-antivirus-windows-phone-app-from-the-marketplace/

There has been a recent SMS flaw discovered:

http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2011/12/14/windows-phone-7-5-susceptible-to-sms-hack/

Having said that, there is still a need to educate developers about security. You can of course build an application which has its own security vulnerabilities by failing to protect the users data for example.

Comment: Yeah, funny that the first malware on Windows Phone, was a real anti-virus app.

Comment: I have seen situations in the past when the entire WP7 application database(XAP files) was downloaded from Marketplace and the entire code was available for the hacker to analyse, as majority of the developers did not use Dotfuscator or any other obfuscation tool to obfuscate the code. But this is an issue with Marketplace and not WP7 Operating System. I also observed that, issues that existed with Apple and Android didnt show up once again in WP7. Hopefully more issues are found in future.

Comment: The SMS flaw was found last month, but I did not find any documentation on how this was done, and what is the fix, if any exists. If someone knows it, please post the link.

Answer (score 2):

> if there are any new vulnerabilities that exist in Windows Phone 7

Actually, I dare say there ain't any old ones either. Most of the security issues on Android is caused by the ability to change the system 110%. Windows Phone don't have intents, don't allow process inspection, or access to the raw file-system.

As Colin said, the security issues there can occur is related to data handling. For instance, the isolated storage can be inspected by jailbreaking the device, and as such you can read out unencrypted passwords (or other personal data) from the isolated storage.

However, to jailbreak a device, you need physical access to it. And you can't remote install a application for inspecting the isolated storage, even if the device was jailbreak'd. It can only be done by USB.